# Why are different URLs returning the same page?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape every page in the data table on this page: https://etfdb.com/tool/etf-stock-exposure-tool/#stock&page=1. As you can see, when you select a new page manually using the buttons on the website, the URL changes accordingly. Also if you change the page number and refresh the URL, the page will update accordingly. However when I run the following loop:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for i in range(1,7): # 6 pages
    page = requests.get('https://etfdb.com/tool/etf-stock-exposure-tool/#stock&page={}'.format(i))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('tbody')
```

`table` (and `page` and `soup`) consistently returns the data from Page 1 no matter what number is in the URL.

How do I make this work (how do I get all the data from the table not just that from the first page)?

Comment: Just tried on the site, and if you go to page 2 and then refresh, although the URL still says page 2, it's page 1 that you actually see. So this won't work with Python requests either, or any HTTP library. The site clearly uses purely client side pagination, and implements it badly to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Data of first page is available in `HTML`. But if you notice when you change the page it does not lode entire the page, it send `AJAX` request and change the data of table. Data of second page filled dynamically using `Javascript` from `JSON`. You can find `AJAX` request in `XHR` tab Under `Network` on your browser.

[image: AJAX Request in NetworkTab]

You have to use `AJAX` request to get data from this webpage.

```
import requests

url = 'https://etfdb.com/data_set/'

limit = 25
offset = 0

while True:
    params = {"tm":"40283","cond":"{\"most_popular\":null}","no_null_sort":"true","count_by_id":"","limit":[limit,limit],"offset":offset}
    response = requests.get(url, params=params)

    json_data = response.json()

    for stock in json_data['rows']:
        print(stock['stock_name'], end=' | ')

    offset += limit
    if json_data['total'] < offset:
        break
```

OutPut:

```
Apple Inc | Abbott Laboratories | Barrick Gold Corp | Accenture <span class="caps">PLC</span> | Analog Devices Inc | Alliance Data Systems Corp | Autodesk Inc | <span class="caps">AGNC</span> Investment Corp | American International Group Inc | Amgen Inc | American Tower Corp | TD Ameritrade Holding Corp | Amazon.com Inc | Apache Corp | ..... | Bank of China Ltd | Samsung Electronics Co Ltd | SoftBank Group Corp
```

Comment: i dont see any difference here. wheres "ajax" call in this?